# How can i fix" Button().isEnabled" error on my app?

Tags: android, kotlin

**I'm trying to make an RNG App and want to disable my Button as long as my animation is running. It shouldn't be too complicated, because I'm a Beginner in Kotlin-App development.**
it crashes after the delay.

I have already tried other ways with my Animation and is tried setEnable().

```
button_randomize.setOnClickListener {
    textView_Number.text = (minRangeRandom..maxRangeRandom).shuffled().first().toString()

    textView_Number.animate().setDuration(500).rotationBy(360f)
    Timer().schedule(object: TimerTask(){
         override fun run() {
             button_randomize.isEnabled = false
          }
          },500)
    button_randomize.isEnabled = true
}
```

I expect that the randomize Button is disabled until the animation is finished. Currently, it crashes when the delay is finished.

Comment: A crash log would have helped..

Comment: try using `View.postDelayed` on your button instead of a timer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's likely because Timer creates a new thread, and your TimerTask is ran on that new thread.
However, the Android UI framework does not support multi-threading. View properties may only be altered on the main thread.

To fix this, use a different way to delay. This executes the delayed code on the main thread:

```
button_randomize.isEnabled = true
button_randomize.postDelayed({
    button_randomize.isEnabled = false
}, 500)
```

Comment: This is a way to sync the animation with the handler hardcoded, this is by far a not good approach.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

```
textView_Number.animate().setDuration(500).rotationBy(360f)
    .withStartAction {
        button_randomize.isEnabled = false
    }.withEndAction {
        button_randomize.isEnabled = true     
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't work sadly but thanks for your submission!

Answer (score 0):

You can add an animator listener to know when it ends, like this

```
textview_Number.animate().setDuration(500).rotationBy(360f).setListener(object : Animator.AnimatorListener {
                override fun onAnimationRepeat(animation: Animator?) {}

                override fun onAnimationCancel(animation: Animator?) {}

                override fun onAnimationStart(animation: Animator?) {}

                override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animator?) {
                     button_randomize.isEnabled = true
                }
            })
        }
```